# Unity: SpeechLib works fine in editor but not in runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine, speech

I am trying to use SpeechLib to implement Text-To-Speech in Unity, it works fine in the editor but I get an exception when running a build on windows. Here is the error:

NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
at System.__ComObject..ctor () [0x00006] in :0
at (wrapper cominterop) SpeechLib.SpVoiceClass..ctor()

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any updates? I am facing same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

Steps:

1. Build Settings
2. Player Settings
3. Make sure you selected "Standalone" tab
4. Open "Other Settings" tab
5. Api Compatibility Level: choose .Net 4.x
6. Save and build